# Manipulating std::string

Tags: c++

The below code does not give any fault/error/warning(although I think there might be some illegal memory access happening). Strangely, the size of the string being printed using 2 different methods(strlen and std::string.size() is coming out differently.

> strlen(l_str.c_str()-> is giving the size as 1500, whereas,
>   l_str.size()-> is giving the size as 0.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void strRet(void* data)
{
        char ar[1500];
        memset(ar,0,1500);
        for(int i=0;i<1500;i++)
                ar[i]='a';
        memset(data,0,1500); // This might not be correct but it works fine
        memcpy(data,ar,1500);
}
int main()
{
        std::string l_str;
        cout<<endl<<"size before: "<<l_str.length();
        int var=10;
        strRet((void *)l_str.c_str());
        printf("Str after call: %s\n",l_str.c_str());
        cout<<endl<<"size after(using strlen): "<<strlen(l_str.c_str());
cout<<endl<<"Size after(using size function): "<<l_str.size();
        printf("var value after call: %d\n",var);
        return 0;
}
```

Please suggest, if I'm doing something which I'm not supposed to do!

Also, I wanted to know which memory bytes are being set to 0 when I do `memset(data,0,1500);`? What I mean to ask is that if suppose, my string variable's starting address is 100, then does memset command sets the memory range [100,1600] as 0? Or is it setting some other memory range?

Comment: Why are you using memsets on a std::string? Use std::fill http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill

Comment: looks like you're having fun playing with undefined behavior there ... you're not allowed to play with more memory in data() than the size of the string

Comment: The C++ `std::string` class is Not A C String. One is an object with state and behaviour, including _very commonly_ a data member storing the length, and the other is a flat array of `char` with a convention that there should be an `\0` at the end.

Comment: `(void *)` stop right there.  There is almost no reason to cast to a `void*` in C++.  You should be working with the `std::string` directly and using its members functions to alter its state.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can explain what exactly is happening in the code. I had mentioned in the question that I suspect that there might be memory access violations, but why the code is giving an output instead of any faults/errors, I'm not able to understand. And also, why are strlen() and str.size() giving different outputs?

Comment: This makes as little sense as something like `void *ptr; memset(ptr, 0, 1500);` It writes to a whole bunch of memory that has not been allocated.

Comment: It _is_ giving errors, this is a valid and expected outcome of UB. The compiler isn't required to issue diagnostics, the runtime isn't required to protect you from yourself. If you do something wrong, _it's just wrong and it's your fault_. There is no requirement that it fail consistently, or comprehensibly.

Comment: Why the down votes? So it's wrong code that does bad things, but isn't that the point of asking a question? At least its a snippet that compiles and reproduces the question. SO can be really rough sometimes.

Comment: @acraig5075 UB questions just attract down votes... usually because of "lack of research"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
memset(data,0,1500); // This might not be correct but it works fine
```

It isn't correct, and it doesn't "work fine". This is Undefined Behaviour, and you're making the common mistake of assuming that if it compiles, and your computer doesn't *instantly* catch fire, everything is fine.

It really isn't.

> I've done something which I wasn't supposed to do!

Yes, you have. You took a pointer to a `std::string`, a non-trivial object with its own state and behaviour, asked it for the address of some memory *it controls*, and cast that to `void*`.

There's no reason to do that, you should *very* rarely ever see `void*` in C++ code, and seeing C-style casts to any type is pretty worrying.

Don't take `void*` pointers into objects with state and behaviour like `std::string` until you understand what you're doing and why this is wrong. Then, when that day comes, you still won't do it because you'll know better.

---

We can look at the first problem in some fine detail, if it helps:

```
(void *)l_str.c_str()
```

- what does `c_str()` return? A pointer to some memory owned by `l_str`
- where is this memory? No idea, that's `l_str`'s business. If this standard library implementation uses the small string optimization, it may be *inside* the `l_str` object. If not, it may be dynamically allocated.
- how much memory is allocated at this location? No idea, that's `l_str`'s business. All we can say for sure is that there is at least one legally-addressable char (`l_str.c_str()[0] == '\0'`) and that it's legal to use the address `l_str.c_str()+1` (but only as a one-past-the-end pointer, so you can't dereference it)

So, the statement

```
strRet((void *)l_str.c_str());
```

passes `strRet` a pointer to a location containing one or more addressable chars, of which the first is zero. That's *everything* we can say about it.

Now let's look again at the problematic line

```
memset(data,0,1500); // This might not be correct but it works fine
```

why would we expect there to be 1500 chars at this location?  If you'd documented `strRet` as requiring a buffer of at least 1500 allocated chars, would it look reasonable to actually pass `l_str.c_str()` when you *know* `l_str` has just been default constructed as an *empty* string? It's not like you asked `l_str` to allocate that storage for you.

You could start to make this work by giving `l_str` a chance to allocate the memory you intend to write, by calling

```
l_str.reserve(1500);
```

before calling `strRet`. This still won't notify `l_str` that you filled it with `'a'`s though, because you did that by changing the raw memory behind its back.

If you want this to work correctly, you could replace the entirety of `strRet` with

```
std::string l_str(1500, 'a');
```

or, if you want to change an existing string correctly, with

```
void strRet(std::string& out) {
    // this just speeds it up, since we know the size in advance
    out.reserve(1500);
    // this is in case the string wasn't already empty
    out.clear();
    // and this actually does the work
    std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(out), 1500, 'a');
}
```

Comment: to be fair - OP doesn't cast the `string` to a `void*`; they cast a `const char*`.... not much better I don't disagree though

Comment: And why is there a difference between the output of strlen and string.size(). What exactly is happening there?

Comment: @VishalSharma `string.size()` is the size that the object has, in the case of `std::string` most likely just a member variable that holds the value. When the string is modified this value is updated. `strlen` on the other hand reads the memory until it reaches a null terminator, and gives that as size.

Comment: When I did, memset(data,0,1500); was I setting 1500 consecutive bytes, starting from the address &l_str(the string variable in my code) as 0?

Comment: @VishalSharma That's what you tried to do. But since you are accessing memory that's not allocated it is UB, and you can no longer have any expectations on the actual result. It could end up doing all sorts of things.