# Using C functions to manipulate std::string

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring

Sometimes you need to fill an `std::string` with characters constructed by a C function.  A typical example is this:

```
constexpr static BUFFERSIZE{256};
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
snprint (buffer, BUFFERSIZE, formatstring, value1, value2);
return std::string(buffer);
```

Notice how we first need to fill a local buffer, and then copy it to the `std::string`.

The example becomes more complex if the maximum buffersize is calculated and not necessarily something you want to store on the stack.  For example:

```
constexpr static BUFFERSIZE{256};
if (calculatedBufferSize>BUFFERSIZE)
   {
   auto ptr = std::make_unique<char[]>(calculatedBufferSize);
   snprint (ptr.get(), calculatedBufferSize, formatstring, value1, value2);
   return std::string(ptr.get());
   }
else
   {
   char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
   snprint (buffer, BUFFERSIZE, formatstring, value1, value2);
   return std::string(buffer);
   }
```

This makes the code even more complex, and if the calculatedBufferSize is larger than what we want on the stack, we essentially do the following:

- allocate memory (make_unique)
- fill the memory with the wanted result
- allocate memory (std::string)
- copy memory to the string
- deallocate memory

Since C++17 `std::string` has a non-const `data()` method, implying that this is the way to manipulate strings.  So it seems tempting to do this:

```
std::string result;
result.resize(calculatedBufferSize);
snprint (result.data(), calculatedBufferSize, formatstring, value1, value2);
result.resize(strlen(result.c_str()));
return result;
```

My experiments show that the last resize is needed to make sure that the length of the string is reported correctly.  `std::string::length()` does not search for a nul-terminator, it just returns the size (just like `std::vector` does).

Notice that we have much less allocation and copying going on:

- allocate memory (resize string)
- fill the memory with the wanted result

To be honest, although it seems to be much more efficient, it also looks very 'un-standard' to me.  Can somebody indicate whether this is behavior allowed by the C++17 standard?  Or is there another way to have this kind of manipulations in a more efficient way?

Please don't refer to question [Manipulating std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735528/manipulating-stdstring), as that question is about much more dirty logic (even using `memset`).
Also don't answer that I must use C++ streams (`std::string_stream`, efficient?, honestly?).  Sometimes you simply have efficient logic in C that you want to reuse.

Comment: why on earth :o

Comment: So why your `calculatedBufferSize` doesn't equal to `strlen(result)`

Comment: if you wish not to have code that looks 'un-standard', then don't mix c and c++. either do the string manipulation with c++ functions or keep using C but don't convert back into std::string and continue your code with char*. (which seems to make more sense considering you want to know the null-terminated string-length and not the actual data length)

Comment: Use asprintf to allocate the buffer then initialize std::string with it. Or call sprintf twice.

Comment: Maybe use some library like fmt. Boost format library?

Comment: If there is a requirement to use the C functions, also consider `std::string_view`. Then you only need to allocate the buffer once. It seems pretty backwards to emulate a `std::string` this way but it would be safe and fast. Just wrap the construct in your own class.

Comment: I just want to point out that if you want this behaviour (stack storage only if small), you should use a container which handles that for you, e.g. [LLVM's SmallVector](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1SmallVector.html).

Comment: Konrad, markus-nm: I agree provided that all code would be written from scratch.  Additionally, functions like sprintf are way more efficient that C++'s << operator (although C++'s << has more flexibility, I agree with that).  So if you have a code base that's 15 to 20 years old, parts of it are written in C, and no time (or incentive?) to rewrite everything in C++, you need these kinds of tricks.  Welcome to the real world.

Comment: @KIIV, Boost format might indeed offer a solution if looking for a efficient replacement of sprint, and I will certainly look at it.  But there are other cases where C functions fill strings.

Comment: @rubenvb, something like SmallVector would indeed make the code shorter, but doesn't solve the unnecessary allocation and copying.

Comment: @Max Langhof, std::string_view is indeed a good improvement in C++17, but doesn't solve the problem here, unless the function that returns the string returns a pair containing the allocated buffer (maybe std::unique_ptr<char[]>) and an std::string_view (luckily we have structured bindings now).  A much better alternative would be to have an std::string constructor where a char-pointer (or std::unique_ptr<char[]>) can be moved into the string (no copy of bytes needed, the std::string just steals the pointer), although this might become complex if the std::string has a custom allocator.

Comment: @Patrick Provided examples can and should be replaced by something safer.  The C format strings are error prone and often it's not that easy to guess correct placeholder type for cstdint types (if you don't know about macros). I took a look about efficiency and boost was slow. But there are others like FastFormat or so.

Comment: @KIIV, thanks for checking the efficiency of Boost.  I will look at FastFormat instead.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modifying the contents pointed to by `data()` is fine, assuming you do not set the value at `data() + size()` to anything other than the null character. From [[string.accessors]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.accessors):

> `charT* data() noexcept;`
>
> *Returns:* A pointer `p` such that `p + i == addressof(operator[](i))` for each `i` in `[0, size()]`.
>
> *Complexity:* Constant time.
>
> *Remarks:* The program shall not modify the value stored at `p + size()` to any value other than `charT()`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

---

The statement `result.resize(strlen(result.c_str()));` does look a bit odd, though. [`std::snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) returns the number of characters written; using that value to resize the string would be more appropriate. Additionally, it looks slightly neater to construct the string with the correct size instead of constructing an empty one that is immediately resized:

```
std::string result(maxlen, '\0');
result.resize(std::max(0, std::snprintf(result.data(), maxlen, fmt, value1, value2)));
return result;
```

Answer (score 4):

The general approach looks fine to me. I would make couple of changes.

1. Capture the return value of `snprinf`.
2. Use it to perform error check and avoid a call to `strlen`.

---

```
std::string result;
result.resize(calculatedBufferSize);
int n = snprint (result.data(), calculatedBufferSize, formatstring, value1, value2);

if ( n < 0 )
{
   // Problem. Deal with the error.
}

result.resize(n);
return result;
```